# how to change StateListDrawable programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there any way 'state' can be changed programmatically for StateListDrawable?

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">

<item
    android:state_checked="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/picker_circle_selected"/>

<item
    android:state_checked="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/picker_circle_today" />
```

```
StateListDrawable backgroundDrawable = (StateListDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.picker_selector);
```

I have tried ....."`selectDrawable(int index)`" and "`addState()`" on `StateListDrawable`. But nothing worked.

By default "`state_checked = false`" drawable gets displayed. When user taps on this drawable it changes it's state to "`state_checked = true`". Is there any way it's state can be changed programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
// call your view
View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(yourlayout, viewGroup, false);

    ColorDrawable colorDrawableSelected = new ColorDrawable(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    StateListDrawable stateListDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
    stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_selected}, colorDrawableSelected);
    stateListDrawable.addState(StateSet.WILD_CARD, null);// set the StateListDrawable as background of the view
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        view.setBackgroundDrawable(stateListDrawable);
    } else {
        view.setBackground(stateListDrawable); 


 then call like this: view.setSelected etc
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change the color of the stat using `LayerDrawable`

```
DrawableContainerState drawableContainerState = (DrawableContainerState) backgroundDrawable.getConstantState();
Drawable[] children = drawableContainerState.getChildren();
LayerDrawable selectedItem = (LayerDrawable) children[0];
LayerDrawable unselectedItem = (LayerDrawable) children[1];


selectedItem.setColor(Color.Black); // changing to black color
```